# freeradius sqlcounter reply-message and coovachilli

Tags: freeradius, coovachilli

The freeradius mailing lists and wiki and all my searching I can't find a workable guide on how the counter reply message is set.

On a default freeradius server time and quota control is working perfectly. The suggestions to enhance the reply message is to add to raddb/sites-availible/default an if statement like this;

```
expiration{
    userlock = 1
}
if(userlock){
        update reply {
                Reply-Message := "Your account - %{User-Name} - has expired, "
        }
        ok = reject
}
```

and this works for expired accounts but when I add another counter like this one below it does not take precedence over the expire counter so the reply is not accurate.

```
 noresetBytecounter{
 reject = 1
}
if(reject){
        update reply {
                Reply-Message := "You have reached your bandwidth limit"
        }
        ok = reject
#}
```

Is the format wrong? If so where on earth is a workable guide...

Answer (score 1):

hello why have you commented the last line that has a } i guess it should be :

```
noresetBytecounter{
 reject = 1
}
if(reject){
        update reply {
                Reply-Message := "You have reached your bandwidth limit"
        }
        ok = reject
}
```